# Android SearchView show hint text before user starts typing

Tags: android, searchview

I have a SearchView and trying to add a hint text. It seems you can only show the hint when the user actually taps on the SearchView, I googled a lot and tried different approaches I found on StackOverflow such as:

```
searchView.onActionViewExpanded();
searchView.setIconified(true);
searchView.setQueryHint("Mitarbeiter suchen");
```

or playing around more with the code above. I also tried adding `IconifiedByDefault` in XML file but it was no help.

I'm sure there's a way for it. Can anyone help, please? :)

**fragment_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
    android:id="@+id/search_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:queryHint="Mitarbeiter suchen">

</android.support.v7.widget.SearchView>
```

Comment: use like tooltip widget for it.for example....https://github.com/jayrambhia/Tooltip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Checks if searchView is focused or not by isFocused() method. If matches, then it will clear focus.

```
searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
searchEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_src_text); //SearchView editText
closeButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.search_close_btn); //X button of SearchView

searchView.onActionViewExpanded(); //new Added line
searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
searchView.setQueryHint("Search Here");

if(!searchView.isFocused()) {
    searchView.clearFocus();
}

//Query
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new 
           SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

            return false;
        }
    });

//This is the your x button
closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Clear the text from EditText view
            searchEditText.setText("");

            //Clear query
            searchView.setQuery("", false);
            searchView.clearFocus();
        }
    });
```

[Here is the screenshot of my demo app and it is in fragment.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q40CE.png)

Comment: No I don't want to show the keyboard or make searchView active by default! I want just to show the text (hint) there.

Comment: Are you sure it is working for you? it doesn't work for me. When I open the fragment, SearcView is active and keyboard is up.

Comment: Bro!! sorry I missed a line. Check out again. Now it will work. I tested in fragment.

Comment: Perfect, just something else, when I start searching and then tap the x button to clear my search, then I can't close my keyboard. is there a way to close it?

Comment: Yes. You can find the x button by findViewById() and code on it. Updated my code. Checkout it.

Comment: ah thank you a lot,  no I meant the built in "x" shaped button on SearchView, I don't know what it is called but it is like a x letter. sorry for confusion and thank you for your code.

Comment: you're welcome. if you have solved then make my answer correct :)

Comment: it didn't solve the keyboard problem but it shows the hint text

Comment: still keyboard opens? please explain the problem... sorry i can't catch it!!

Comment: The search view is showing hints only after tapping on the search view. I have added the above code snippet it's not working.

Answer (score 18):

Setting `iconifiedByDefault` and `focusable` properties to `false` worked for me.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    app:queryHint="test" />
```

Answer (score 3):

> If you want the search field to always be visible, then call
>   setIconifiedByDefault(false)

Programmatically `setIconifiedByDefault(false)`

In XML
 `app:iconifiedByDefault="false"`

Comment: No I don't want to show the keyboard or make searchView active by default! I want just to show the text (hint) there.